# What is wrong with this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, web

I have two checkboxes name check1 and check2. I wanted for either one to be disabled if the other one was checked. This is what I did:

```
var male = document.getElementById("check1");
var female = document.getElementById("check2");

male.disabled = (female.checked == true) ? true : false;
female.disabled = (male.checked == true) ? true : false;
```

It does not work at all. Is the syntax correct. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can check for javascript syntax errors with : http://jslint.com/. It has a slight learning curve but its extremely useful.

Comment: @havok, how is that useful in this particular case?

Comment: Consider using radio buttons instead of checkboxes. The user is likely to be less confused by radio buttons behaving normally than by checkboxes behaving like radio buttons.

Comment: @J-P, part of his question was whether his syntax is correct. jslint can confirm that it is. It doesn't answer his question so thats why I only put it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `onchange` event, and your code could be tidied up as well.

```
var male = document.getElementById("check1"),
    female = document.getElementById("check2");

male.onchange = function() {
    female.disabled = male.checked;
};

female.onchange = function() {
    male.disabled = female.checked;
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DTek6/).

Also, shouldn't you be using radio input?

Comment: You need to remove extra closing brackets after functions. Here is a working example uses jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/wAukf/

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` shouldn't be set at all in order to be disabled AFAIK, any value is "truthy"

do `.removeAttribute('disabled')` to not have it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the state of the other checkbox when one is clicked eg. male changed - alter female, and versa verse.

```
function maleOnClick(){
    female.checked= !this.checked;
}
function femaleOnClick(){
    male.checked= !this.checked;
}
```

Anyway why dont you use `type="radio"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 male.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); //set
 male.setAttribute('disabled', ''); //clear
```

So:

```
male.setAttribute = (female.checked == true) ? 'disabled': '';
```